# OpenCV 2.2 Does not open Camera

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, camera

I would like to use camera and perform image processing on the input stream, but when program is executed a window appears asking 'Capture Source' after which when 'OK' or 'Apply' nothing happens.

But if I use video file instead of camera, the program runs perfectly fine.

Here is the code:

```
int MainWindow::on_CameraOpen_triggered()
{
// programming done in Qt and using Opencv 2.2.
// all the variables are defined & declared in private of header file
// there is no compilation error
// return type of the function is 'int'
// Following program works fine if name of video file is mentioned 
// instead of '0' is the line below
VideoCapture capture(0);

if(!capture.isOpened())
    return 1;

    bool stop(false);
    double rate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    namedWindow("Extracted Frame");
    int delayVideo = 1000/rate;

    while(!stop)
    {
        if(!capture.read(frame))
        {
            break;
        }
        imshow("Extracted frame", frame);
        if(waitKey(delayVideo)>=0)
        {
            stop = true;
        }
    }

capture.release();
}
```

I have tried to remove the bug which was rectified at following link: 
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/changeset/4400

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp?rev=4400

Camera works fine on gtalk and other camera softwares.

Kindly suggest/guide what can be done.

Thank you very much.

Regards,
dbs

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
# include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

CvCapture *_capture;


_capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
//_capture = cvCaptureFromFile("test1.mp4");
if (!_capture)
{
    //"Unable capture video"
    return 1;
}

double rate = cvGetCaptureProperty(_capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

//...

cv::Mat = cvQueryFrame(_capture);

//...
```

Comment: Hi could u please explain/clarify what should be there in '//...' part of the code you mentioned w.r.t. to my code in post. I have never used any versions of opencv before 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is another minimal example you can use to examine if everything works correctly with OpenCV:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main () {
    cv::VideoCapture cam = cv::VideoCapture(0);
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow ("Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (1) {
        cam >> frame;
        imshow ("Demo", frame);
    }

    cam.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Try it to see if the problem lies with OpenCV or your Qt program.